# format-table outputting blank?

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is look at some processes and get a list of the user of these processes. ANd the following code worked fine for me.

```
get-wmiobject win32_process |
where{$_.name -like "*notepad*"}|sort {$_.CommandLine}|
select @{n="User";e={$_.getowner().user}},@{n="ProcessID";e={$_.ProcessID}},{$_.CommandLine} |ft -AutoSize |Out-String -Width 300 >> C:\ListUsers.txt
```

Somehow I wanted to split the $_.CommandLine string in the middle of way, and output some of the split arrary(see the following code for a better idea, although the code is wrong). But the updated code just output nothing into the text file. I think I must be using the select-object or fommat-object wrong, but i don't know how i can fix it.

```
get-wmiobject win32_process |
where{$_.name -like "*notepad*"}|sort {$_.CommandLine}|
%{
$split = $_.CommandLine.split("\")    
select @{n="User";e={$_.getowner().user}},@{n="ProcessID";e={$_.ProcessID}},@{n="Ihub";e=$split[3]},@{n="version";e=$split[3]},@{n="version";e=$split[3]} |
ft -AutoSize |Out-String -Width 300 >> C:\ListUsers.txt
}
```

Can anyone advise? Thanks!!

Comment: As said below, I've updated the answer now. BUT what are you trying to do? You search for "notepad" (which normally can give you either "notepad.exe" or "notepad++.exe") processes. Then you take out a hard-coded part of the path? Where's the logic in that? :P If you know the process name(since you searched for it), why try to split it out? Also, in some cases you might just get `\somefolder\` as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `select` and then `format-table`. `Format-table` can create calculated properties too. Also, you forgot to wrap the `$split[3]` in a scriptblock. I removed the two "version" properties because they were identical to "Ihub".

Try this(untested):

```
get-wmiobject win32_process |
where{$_.name -like "*notepad*"}|sort {$_.CommandLine} | 
Format-Table -Property @{n="User";e={$_.getowner().user}},@{n="ProcessID";e={$_.ProcessID}},@{n="Ihub";e={($_.CommandLine.split("\"))[3]}} -AutoSize | 
Out-String -Width 300 >> ListUsers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Though.. are you sure about your code, it doesn't seem to be working for me:)

Comment: As said, this is untested. I didn't have PS available

Comment: I've updated it now. Forgot to output the object before formatting. Rewrote it to use normal pipeline instead of foreach.